# 2 subview to window?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have this at my appdelegate:

for 1st app:

```
   - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

   [window addSubview:rootController.view];
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
  }
```

this will display a navigation and tabar display for my app.

ok no problem here.

next i have this from another app:

```
   - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
      _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

     MainViewController *_mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
      UINavigationController *_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_mainViewController];

     [_window addSubview:_navigationController.view];
       [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
       }
```

which also works fine.

now, how can i include all this function into my 1st app? i would like to use it for one of my tab options.

i've tried:

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    Tab4 *_mainViewController = [[Tab4 alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_mainViewController];

    [window addSubview:_navigationController.view];
[window addSubview:rootController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

sort of combining the two. there is no compiling error but the program is not working.
i got it wrong somewhere and stuck. is it possible to have 2 subivew?
any help is greatly appreciated.
thks.

hi,

i've embedded the a nav controller in my tab bar.
but doing this does it "replace" the code completely?

```
      _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

     MainViewController *_mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
      UINavigationController *_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_mainViewController];

     [_window addSubview:_navigationController.view];
       [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

tab view gets load up fine but it is unable to receive a notification.
thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TabBarController should be the only subview to the window, and a window should have only 1 subview.  Include the navigation controller inside one of the tabs.  A TBC **cannot** be used inside of a navigationController.  [Here](http://b00gizm.posterous.com/how-to-embed-a-navigation-controller-inside-a) is a simple tutorial showing you how to add a navigation controller to a tab.  Also, you should [read the Apple Documentation on Tab Bars](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Any view can have 0 .. n subviews, the main window included.
What are the frames of the two subviews?  Maybe one is just sitting on top of the other and is therefore hidden.